# Chain rule with two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $f(x,y)$ is a function of two variables with $f_x(0,2)=2$ and  $f_y(0,2)=-1$. Using the chain rule, compute the numerical value of  $f_\theta(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=2$ at $r=2$, $ \theta = \frac{\pi}{2} $

For some reason I seem to be stuck on this question. Could someone please just give me some hints on what I need to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$f_{\theta}(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))=f_x(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}+f_y(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}$$

Comment: Isn't $x = x(r, \theta)$? Same for $y$.

Comment: Sure, I will edit it in my answer. Thanks!